# Separate buttons on navigation drawer

Tags: android, textview, navigation-drawer, android-button

in my app I use a navigation drawer and I found out that it's much more comfortable for me to use the ListView.AddFooter in order to add buttons instead of getting stuff complicated with the TextView. I added 4 buttons and they all look good, but when I change the background color they become weird - instead of round in the corners they become rectangles, and not separated - they touch eachother and it looks ugly. How do I separate them?

Is there any good tutorial that shows how to add buttons and titles/separators on navigation drawer with TextView? Or maybe I can redesign everything by adding Views?

thanks in advance, 
Edo

Answer (score 0):

Your button issue isn't specific to the navigation drawer.  If you set the background on a button to a color, the previously styled button with rounded corners, shadows, etc is now just a single flat color.  To define another color for your button as you are attempting, you will need to recreate the button using a layer-list and shape drawables. See [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html) for information about drawables.